# how to show tab bar like iphone

Tags: android

how to show tab bar below of the screen like in iphone in android?

Comment: If your are using Titanium Developer.. Then i will suggest you to create a view like tab bar, since android shows the tabs on top of the screen

Comment: but sir in android tabs also possible in below of screen...more importantly tab bar is possible in android or not pls pls. tell me sir its yrgent..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using the Dashboard Pattern, applying graphics and style to look exactly as you want.

https://gist.github.com/882650

[Android UI design patterns Presentation from Google I/O 2010](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html&ei=Ez2pTfTEHpS4sAP7zrX6DA&usg=AFQjCNHeabSEyiI-MOD1LoWmpjL2y8pYxA&sig2=ra3-P2chIxiJ-iQZSwx5Tw)